# Dynamically Created/Copied Div in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net

For some back story on what I am trying to do. I am building a web based calculator to help me build out a phone system. The system can handle multiple sites but each site needs an unit that can handle both the number of phones on the site and the PSTN Ports on the site. The issue I have is that the site limit is 20 sites so building a DIV for each and every site is crazy. I want to find a way to make the system automate the creation of these devs on the screen ether by server side or client side actions (assuming this is going to take some issue to load server side may be better) Here is the Div I created so far:

```html
<div id="Site1" runat="server" class="col-md-1">
        Site 1:        
        <br />Phones:<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="Phones" runat="server" type="number" min ="1" Text="1" Width="72px" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />T1 Ports:<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="T1" runat="server" type="number" min ="0" Text="0" step ="1" Width="72px" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />FXO Ports:<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="FXO" runat="server" type="number" min ="0" Text="0" step="2" Width="72px" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />FXS Ports:<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="FXS" runat="server" type="number" min ="0" Text ="0" step="2" Width="72px" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
        <hr />
    </div>
```

I would ideally re create it and all of the text boxes with new variables each time. I know cloning the div with nothing but data in it isn't looking to hard but creating this one time after time seems to be fooling me

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to build a user control and include all of your divs in it. Then you could use something like a repeater to create as many of your div collections as you need.

Comment: With this repeater would it name each of the Div Components generically or can I command the naming convention as well. I have to admit I am not to familiar with the controls

Comment: You could do either but you really don't need to. You expose them as properties from a user control. Then when you repeat them you're just giving your user controls names and then accessing their properties. For example, myUserControl_1.Phone = "555-555-5555". Inside of the user control your textbox "Phones" is set to the property "Phone".

Comment: Here's a pretty good example that should get you going: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET

Comment: Now the other concern I have in this Control Structure is the use of the variables created in the replication being usable in the larger goal of the program. The replication of the DIV will include the replication of some user inputs that would hopefully go into globally available variables and thus used in the main program that I am trying to wright

Comment: That's not the way it works. You would expose them as properties of the control. Example var myControl = new YourControl(); myControl.yourPropertyName; They aren't global variables, they are just properties of your control the same way you use ".Text" on a asp:TextBox. "Text" is just a public property of that control.

Comment: So I would have to use them as properties to work in them. I got some Ideas now. Thank you